# web worker console.log

Tags: html, console, web-worker

Is it just me, or is `console.log()` too much to ask for from HTML5 web workers?

I know that manipulating the DOM is blocked because it is potentially dangerous, but is there really any possibility that `console.log()` could be maliciously exploited by a multithreaded worker?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Agreed things would be a lot nicer, but it's not too hard to hack up a primitive `console.log` using `postMessage`. David Flanagan has a nice wrapper [here](https://github.com/davidflanagan/WorkerConsole/).

Comment: Nice wrapper indeed, but unfortunately the way it is implemented does not allow the use of jQuery.Hive.

Comment: I would suggest to use Chrome dev tools (form 17+) - then you will get a nice option to debug your workers without the need to use console.log

Comment: Debugging is not the same as console logging, they have different but slightly overlapping usecases.

Answer (score 25):

Just wanted to post that console.log is now possible at least within the Chrome Browser.

I do not know which version it was added but 35.0.1916.153 m has it.

**Limitation**

There is a small limitation with it though, It can only output primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) sometimes single dimension arrays.

And it can only take the **first** argument within the console log.

Normal Console log:

```
console.log("status:", _status); // status: working
console.log({ status: _status }); // { "status": working }
```

Worker Console log:

```
console.log("status:", _status); // status:
console.log({ status: _status }); // [object Object]
```

You could use `console.log(JSON.stringify({ status: _status }));` but this would not handle circular referencing objects and will not output in a pretty/easy to read objects.

**Update:** You can get pretty print with stringify by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject, null, "  "));`.

Comment: As of may 2020, `console.log` is also available in Firefox (v75.0).
I do not now either when it was added

Comment: Works in Edge too, at least [since version 12](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

Comment: you also need to toggle the JavaScript context for chrome as demonstrated [here](https://lihautan.com/Debugging%20web%20workers/)