# console.log is not pretty printing an object in web worker, instead it just shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, console, web-worker

I am passing an object to a web worker, and priot to passing it console.log pretty prints it with clickable properties. Now, inside web worker when I do a console.log I just get an

```
[object Object]
```

I can get the object printed like

> console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

but this is not the same as that pretty console log in the main window.

How could I get that pretty print here as well?

PS Meanwhile I found this answer [web worker console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251779/web-worker-console-log) as I was typing the question. So, console is not implemented for web workers?